# Linux cli tool to dump SQL Server schema to a text file

Tags: sql-server, linux, command-line

Do you know a reliable command line tool able to export SQL Server schema to a text file?

Answer (score 13):

You can do this with mssql-scripter. Download through - `pip install mssql-scripter`.

The command you'll want to use is along the lines of:

```
$ mssql-scripter -S serverName -d databaseName -U user > ./my-schema.sql
```

The default is schema only (you can also specify `--schema-and-data` and `--data-only`). The command line will prompt for your password.

And you can pipe to stdout, sed, or a .sql file currently. Here's the GitHub page as this is an OSS repo - https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-scripter. Please do file issues on the repo if you run into any.