# Is there a linux command line tool for MSSQL/SQLSRV that would allow creating dumps and importing them?

Tags: php, sql-server

Im looking for a linux command line tool for MSSQL/SQLSRV that would allow me to do equivalent commands to these -

`pg_dump --clean --dbname=postgresql://username:password@host:port/database >b database/dump.sql`

`psql postgresql://username:password@host:port/database < database/dump.sql`

This is meant for automatic browser automation testing where base data gets generated and before every test gets reverted to the base state.

The project uses docker for everything and is written mainly in `PHP` but I will gladly look at other ways of accomplishing these needs if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried google?

Comment: What's wrong with `sqlcmd`, `bcp`, or the `SqlServer` library in Powershell?

Comment: @Larnu Can you give an example on how i could achieve a .sql dump with one of these commands? I have found these, but it seems they do dumps of just text. And I do not have access to powershell, As I mentioned in the post, i need this to work in a linux environment, as these commands would be run inside a docker container (ubuntu or alpine).

Comment: You can't script out a database like that in SQL Server, @DaveLV . If you want all the definitions for your objects then ensure your database is in a database project. If you just want to revert the database to a point in time, use your backups.

Comment: (Side note, Powershell has been available on Linux for several years, so if you install it, you do have access to it.)

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for your comments but I answered my own question on how to accomplish this and make a sql dump from sqlserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finding this stackoverflow answer - [Linux cli tool to dump SQL Server schema to a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43669041/linux-cli-tool-to-dump-sql-server-schema-to-a-text-file) that links to a microsoft tool - https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-scripter

And going down a rabbit hole of bugs, fixes and patches - https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-scripter/issues/236#issuecomment-886079545

I managed to make a working container for these needs.

Heres a dockerfile part that allows anyone to get the tools needed to accomplish this -

```
FROM ubuntu:21.04

# ....

ARG sqltools=https://github.com/microsoft/sqltoolsservice/releases/download/v3.0.0-release.205/Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer-rhel-x64-net6.0.tar.gz

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y msodbcsql18 mssql-tools18 python pip libunwind8 tar \
     && update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 1 \
     && pip install mssql-scripter \
     && curl -SL $sqltools -o Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer.tar.gz \
     && mkdir Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer \
     && tar -xzf Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer.tar.gz -C Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer \
     && mv Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer /opt/Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer \
     && sed -i 's/utf-8/utf-16/g' /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/mssqlscripter/main.py

ENV MSSQLTOOLSSERVICE_PATH=/opt/Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer

# ....
```

Whats happening here is that we have to download and specify a newer version of sqltoolsservice that works with the newer openssl lib. Then we patch a bug with utf8 and set the ENV variable for mssql-scripter to use the correct sqltools.

After all that its possible to run this command that dumps sql.

`mssql-scripter -S host -d database -U sa -P password --schema-and-data  > database/dump.sql`

And then this command that imports it.

`/opt/mssql-tools18/bin/sqlcmd -S host -d database -U sa -P password -i database/dump.sql`

Comment: I really wanted this to work in 2023, but the Docker image fails to build for various reasons. Ubuntu 21.04 cannot find security updates. Changed to 22.04, cannot find python. Changed references to python2, cannot find specific msodbcsql18 and tools.